# Displaying a diagonal of the matrix specified by the inputed number

Tags: c, matrix

Create a program that creates a matrix, and depending on inputed number K it displays a specific matrix. [Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvkFp.jpg)

I get weird numbers for K>0 and K<0.

```
int main()
{
    int A[20][20],N,K,i,j;
    printf("Dimension: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Enter K: ");
    scanf("%d",&K);
    printf("Enter elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            scanf("%d",&A[i][i]);
    if(K==0)
        for(i=0,j=0;i<N;i++,j++)
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);
    else if (K>0)
        for(j=K,i=0;j<N;j++,i++)
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);
    else
        for(i=-K,j=0;i<N;i++,j++)
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&A[i][i]);` looks like a typo; you probably mean `scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);`

Comment: ^^ I had to look at that four times to see what your were on about:)

Comment: Then again, just looking at that question code is enough to make one char-blind:(

Comment: Thanks. How do I close the question now?

Comment: It's not the prettiest you've ever seen??

Comment: @Desperado please don't close the question just because you have an answer. It's very frustrating for people following, commenting, or answering it. Leave it to the community to delete if they feel it's not worth keeping.

Comment: Didn't mean that. Some kind of answered mark, I thought.

Comment: the 'N' input needs to be checked for the upper limit (20)  and the prompt needs to be modified to indicate the allowed range, similar to 1...20

Comment: the 'K' input needs to be checked for +/- N-1 range and the prompt needs to be modified to indicate that allowed range

Comment: this for() loop `for(j=K,i=0;j<N;j++,i++)` and the other for() loop have the incorrect terminating value, it should be similar to 'N- (abs(K)'  Then it should be obvious that none of the if/elseif/else is needed, just one for() loop for the output

Comment: the code would be massively more readable if prompt/input groups were separated by a blank line and if  code blocks were separated by a blank line.   Also, the use of meaningful variable names would make the code much easier to read.  Names like 'matrixSize'  'whichDiaginal' 'row' 'column'

Comment: the comment by @MOehm is a good start on fixing the code, but it is not the only problem.  I.E. this question is not yet answered

Comment: @user3629249: You make some good points about enforcing the hardcoded limit for `N` and adding whitespace for readability. The present code is well behaved for any `k`, though, and just won't print anything if it has a value out of range.

Comment: And I don't agree about your suggestions for variable names. In a small program like this, the (local) variable names are okay. `A` and `N` are good names for a matrix and its size, `i` and `j` are canonical names for the cols and rows of a matrix (although the OP has got them the wrong way round) and `K` is clear from the problem description. I think overlong variable names make the code harder to read. If you must be explicit about your data, write a comment for the variable definition instead of carrying around the overhead of a long name throughout the code.

Comment: @MOehm,  on most any significant project, (or even a small project that YOU will be maintaining, that was written by someone else (or even your self after a year or two) You will want to be able to simply read the project and have the code, especially the variable names, tell you what is going on, without having to intimately know all the details of the project.   I.E. get the OP into programming for the future, rather than just getting some code on paper that works, now, but will be a major pain to maintain down the road.  So, meaningful names, coding style, etc are very significant details.

Comment: @user3629249 feel free to edit the code to make it more readable. I would like to see it.(Without changing names of variables)

Comment: @user3629249: Thanks for lecturing me. I still maintain that the `A`, `N`, `k`, `i` and `j`  are better names than the ones you proposed. We are talking about local variables of a `main` function that can be seen in its entirety in the editor, not about global or file-scope variables of a larger project, mind. (At least we seem to agree that the crammed, brace-less coding style is horrible.)

Comment: I re-reviewed the if/elseif/else part of the code.  I must have missed a detail the other day, as those loops do work correctly (I tested them).  SO now, I think the 'K' value should be tested, when input, to assure it is within the range -N < K < N and if not, a error message output to the user and program exited

Answer (score 0):

Desperado,

As requested, readable, with all comments incorporated except names unchanged to protect the guilty :-).

Note: error checking added, except for the values within the matrix cells, however any call to `scanf()` should be error checked, even for the values in the matrix cells.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MATRIX_MAX_SIZE (20)
#define MATRIX_MIN_SIZE (2)

int main( void )
{
    int A[MATRIX_MAX_SIZE][MATRIX_MAX_SIZE]; // max size of matrix
    int N;  // size of square matrix along one edge
    int K;  // which diagonal selected
    int i;  // row index
    int j;  // column index

    while(1)
    {
        printf( "Enter square matrix edge length: range %d...%d ",
                MATRIX_MIN_SIZE,
                MATRIX_MAX_SIZE );

        if( 1 != scanf("%d",&N) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for matrix edge length failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else scanf successful

        if( N < MATRIX_MIN_SIZE || N > MATRIX_MAX_SIZE )
        {
            printf( "Input value: %d is outside allowed range\n", N);
        }

        else
        { // else, valid matrix size selector
            break;
        }
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf( "Enter which Diagonal to display: range is %d to %d: ",
                -(N-1),
                (N-1) );

        if( 1 != scanf("%d",&K) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for which diagonal to display failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        if( K < -(N-1) || K > (N-1) )
        {
            printf( "Diagonal Selector: %d is outside the available range\n", K );
        }

        else
        { // else, valid diagonal selector
            break;
        } // endif
    }

    printf( "Enter %d elements\n", (N*N) );

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            // note: call to scanf() needs to have error checking added
            // note: mod to use proper column number 'j'
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);  
        } // end for
    } // end for

    if(0 == K) // always place literal value on left so compiler can catch syntax error
    {
        for( i=0,j=0; i<N; i++,j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", A[i][j] ); // insert space so output numbers separated
        } // end for
    }

    else if (K>0)
    {
        for( j=K,i=0; j<N; j++,i++ )
        {
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]); // insert space so output numbers separated
        } // end for
    }

    else
    {
        for( i=-K,j=0; i<N; i++,j++ )
        {
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]); // insert space so output numbers separated
        } // end for
    } // end if

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Note: it would be better to not have a max matrix size but rather let the user input a value and then malloc the necessary size.